# What is wrong with my Query Importrange in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What is wrong with this code?

It is supposed to only gather the data in the is range for cols 1,2,3,5,11 for the name Bob that contain False. In my results I'm getting data that are TRUE. If I change 'not Col25 = 'True' to Col25 = 'False', I get no results at all.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(" "Master!A:AB"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col5,Col11 
  where Col11 = 'Bob'
  AND not Col25 = 'TRUE'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need to use importrange there.

Try the following formula:

```
=QUERY(Master!A:AB, 
 "select A,B,C,E,K 
  where K = 'Bob'
  AND Y = FALSE")
```

### Result on my sheet:

[image]

**NOTE:** Make sure that the FALSE and TRUE values are setted as automatic and not in plain text:

[image]